# MySQL 5.5.47 table switches itself from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm working with a decade old website that hosts a database with a search function. I was having issues with search function as it would return the following error: The used table type doesn’t support FULLTEXT indexes. I quick search deemed that the table was using the wrong engine type and I switched it from InnoDB to MyISAM. The search function then worked perfectly. However, a few moments later and the search function had stopped working. The table had been reverted back to InnoDB. I took a closer look at the code on the site and it appears that a page called KT_MXSearch.class.php appears to cycle, DROP/CREATE, the table 'src_cache_cah' which is used to house the potential results. I'm trying to have the code stop from changing back from MyISAM. I'm a noob at PHP and this is a bit overwhelming so I'm hoping someone here may be able to help. The database runs on MySQL 5.5.47 - Maria DB and we can't upgrade versions. Thanks for reading. Here is the code:

```
<?php
class KT_MXSearch{
    var $connection; //connection name
    var $databaseType; //database type
    var $searchName; //name of the class
    var $tmpTable; //name of the temporary table storing last cache update
    var $refreshCacheDelay;
    var $cacheTable; //name of the cache table storing all site search content
    var $searchType; //type of search (fulltext || normal)
    var $searchColumns; //array with the names of the searched columns
    var $whereCondition; //where condition in the Search Recordset SQL
    var $orderBy; //order by statement in the Search Recordset SQL
    var $searchFor=''; //aditional columns in the Search Recordset SQL
    var $tables;
    var $totalRows;
    var $importanceArray = array(1=>5,2=>10,3=>25,4=>50,5=>100);
    var $sql = array(
        'create_cache' => "CREATE TABLE %s (
                        title_cah varchar (100) NOT NULL, 
                        shortdesc_cah text NOT NULL, 
                        col1_cah text NULL, 
                        col2_cah text NULL, 
                        col3_cah text NULL, 
                        col4_cah text NULL, 
                        col5_cah text NULL, 
                        importance_cah INT NOT NULL, 
                        url_cah varchar (255) NOT NULL);",
        'select' => "SELECT `%s` as title_cah, `%s` as shortdesc_cah, `%s` as url_cah, %s as importance_cah",                       
        'MySQL' => array(
            'like' => "LIKE",   
            'fulltext_where' => array(
                        'fulltext' => "MATCH (col%s_cah) AGAINST ('%s') >0 ",
                        'boolean fulltext' => "MATCH (col%s_cah) AGAINST ('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) >0 "
                        ),
            'fulltext_order' => array(
                        'fulltext' => "MATCH (col%s_cah) AGAINST ('%s') * %s",
                        'boolean fulltext' => "MATCH (col%s_cah) AGAINST ('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * %s"
                        )
        )       
    );
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   KT_MXSearch
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   KT_MXSearch constructor
    //   
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   searchName - Name of the object
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function KT_MXSearch() {
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   setConnection
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Sets the connection and the connection type (database type)
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   connection - connection name
    //   databaseType - database type
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function setConnection(&$connection , $databaseType) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->databaseType = $databaseType;
    }
    

    
    function setCache($cacheTable, $refreshCacheDelay) {
        $this->cacheTable = $cacheTable;
        $this->refreshCacheDelay = $refreshCacheDelay*60;
    }
    
    function setTempTable($tmpTable) {
        $this->tmpTable = $tmpTable;
    }
    
    function setTables($config) {
        $this->tables = $config->Tables;
    }
    function setSearchType($searchType) {
        $this->searchType = $searchType;
    }
    
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   checkTableExists()
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Verifies the existence of a table in the database
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   tableName - name of the table
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   true or false
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function checkTableExists($tableName){
        //check if table exists
        $KT_sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
        $testRecord = mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection);
        if (mysql_error()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   createTmpTable
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Creates the table that holds the cache refresh information
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function createTmpTable(){
        //create settings table
        $KT_sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$this->tmpTable."(
                                lastupd_tmp TEXT NOT NULL                               
                                );";
        mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());                              
        //insert record
        $this->initTmpTable();
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   updateTmpTable
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Updates the table that holds the cache refresh information
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   true or false
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function updateTmpTable(){
        $now = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
        $KT_sql = "update ".$this->tmpTable." SET lastupd_tmp = '$now'";
        mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
        return true;
    }
    
    
    function initTmpTable() {
        $KT_sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->tmpTable." (lastupd_tmp) VALUES('1970/01/01 00:00:00')  ;";
        mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());                              
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   checkCacheExpired
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Checks if the cache has expired
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   true or false
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function checkCacheExpired() {
        $KT_sql = "select lastupd_tmp from ".$this->tmpTable;
        $mxs_result = mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_mxs_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($mxs_result);
        if ($row_mxs_result['lastupd_tmp']) {
            $date = $row_mxs_result['lastupd_tmp'];
            if (strtotime(date("Y/m/d H:i:s")) - strtotime($date) > $this->refreshCacheDelay) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $this->initTmpTable();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   createCacheTable
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Creates the cache table
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function createFulltextIndex($dbType) {
        if ($dbType=="MySQL") {
            for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
                $KT_sql = 'ALTER TABLE `'.$this->cacheTable.'` DROP INDEX `idx_description`'.$i;
                mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection);
                $KT_sql = 'create fulltext index idx_description'.$i.' on '.$this->cacheTable.' (col'.$i.'_cah);';
                mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error()."<br>Please check that your database supports fulltext search");
            }
        }
    } 
    
    function createCacheTable() {
        $KT_sql = "drop table ".$this->cacheTable;
        mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection);
        $KT_sql = sprintf($this->sql['create_cache'], $this->cacheTable);
        mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
        
        if ($this->searchType=='fulltext') {
            $this->createFulltextIndex($this->databaseType);
        }       
         
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   fillCacheTable
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Fills the cache table
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function fillCacheTable() {
        $this->updateTmpTable();        
        $this->createCacheTable();
        
        if (is_array($this->tables)){
        foreach($this->tables as $tableKey => $crtTable){
            $columnsString = array();
            
            $KT_TableName = $tableKey;

            //for each column...
    
            if (is_array($crtTable['searchColumns'])){
                $tmpColumnArr = array();
                foreach($crtTable['searchColumns'] as $fieldKey => $fieldValue) {
                    $tmpColumnArr[$fieldValue][]    =   "`".$fieldKey."`";
                }
                for ($relIdx=1;$relIdx<=5;$relIdx++) {
                    if (isset($tmpColumnArr[$relIdx])) {
                        $columnsString[$relIdx] = implode(",",$tmpColumnArr[$relIdx]);
                    } else {
                        unset ($columnsString[$relIdx]);
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }else {
                die('No search columns defined in table '.$KT_TableName.'!');
            }
            //end columns
            
            //set the columns values    
            $cacheTile          = $crtTable['resultTitle'];
            $cacheDesc          = $crtTable['resultDesc'];          
            $cacheURL           = $crtTable['pageName'];
            $cacheImportance    = $crtTable['TableImportance'];
            if (isset($crtTable['AditionalCondition'])) {
                $cacheAditionalCond = $crtTable['AditionalCondition'];          
            } else {
                unset($cacheAditionalCond);
            }
            
            //compute result url parameters
            $paramValue = $crtTable['pageParam'];
                
            $KT_sql = sprintf($this->sql['select'], $cacheTile, $cacheDesc, $paramValue, $cacheImportance);
            for ($relIdx=1;$relIdx<=5;$relIdx++) {
                if (isset($columnsString[$relIdx])) {
                    $KT_sql .= ", ".$columnsString[$relIdx];    
                }
            }
            $KT_sql .= " FROM ".$KT_TableName;
            if (isset($cacheAditionalCond) && $cacheAditionalCond != '') {
                $KT_sql .= " WHERE $cacheAditionalCond ";
            }

            $KT_results = mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error()."<br>".$KT_sql);
            $row_KT_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($KT_results);
                
            do {
                $cacheCol = array();
                $col_cah = array();
                $title_cah          = addslashes(strip_tags($row_KT_results['title_cah']));
                $shortdesc_cah      = addslashes(strip_tags($row_KT_results['shortdesc_cah']));
                for ($relIdx=1;$relIdx<=5;$relIdx++) {
                    if (isset($tmpColumnArr[$relIdx])) {
                        $cacheCol[$relIdx] = "";
                        for ($colIdx=0;$colIdx<count($tmpColumnArr[$relIdx]);$colIdx++) {
                            $cacheCol[$relIdx] .= "\r\n".$row_KT_results[str_replace("`", "", $tmpColumnArr[$relIdx][$colIdx])];
                        }
                    }
                }                           
                $KT_colString = ''; $KT_valueString = '';
                for ($relIdx=1;$relIdx<=5;$relIdx++) {
                    if (isset($cacheCol[$relIdx])) {
                        $col_cah[$relIdx] = addslashes(strip_tags($cacheCol[$relIdx]));
                        $KT_colString .= ", col".$relIdx."_cah";
                        $KT_valueString .= ", '".$col_cah[$relIdx]."'";
                        if ($this->databaseType=="PostgreSQL" && $this->searchType=="fulltext") {
                            $KT_colString .= ", col".$relIdx."_vect_cah";
                            $KT_valueString .= ", to_tsvector('".$col_cah[$relIdx]."')";                
                        }
                    } else {
                        $col_cah[$relIdx] = "";
                    }
                }
                $url_cah    = addslashes($cacheURL.$row_KT_results['url_cah']);
                $importance_cah = $this->importanceArray[$cacheImportance];
                $KT_sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->cacheTable." (title_cah, shortdesc_cah".$KT_colString.", importance_cah, url_cah) values ('$title_cah', '$shortdesc_cah'".$KT_valueString.", $importance_cah, '$url_cah');";
                mysql_query($KT_sql) or die(mysql_error());
            } while ($row_KT_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($KT_results));
                
        }//foreach table
        }else {die('No search tables defined!');}
    }
    
    function getRecordset($start = null, $max = null) {
        $kt_searchWhere = $this->getWhereCondition();
        $kt_searchOrder = $this->getOrderBy();
        $kt_columns = $this->getSearchColumns();
        $KT_sql = sprintf("SELECT * %s FROM %s WHERE %s ORDER BY %s", $kt_columns, $this->cacheTable, $kt_searchWhere, $kt_searchOrder);
        $KT_result = mysql_query($KT_sql, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
        $this->totalRows = mysql_num_rows($KT_result);
        if (isset($start) && isset($max)) {
            $KT_result = mysql_query($KT_sql." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$max, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
        }
        return $KT_result;
    }
    
    function getTotalRows() {
        return $this->totalRows;
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   refreshCache
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Checks if the cache is expired and refreshes the cache if necesary
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function refreshCache(){
        if (!$this->checkTableExists($this->tmpTable)){
                $this->createTmpTable($this->tmpTable);
            }
        if ($this->checkCacheExpired()){
                $this->fillCacheTable();
            } 
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   computeAll
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Checks the type of the search and performs the right search
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   searchFor - expression to search for
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function computeAll($searchFor){
        $this->refreshCache();
        $this->setSearchTerm($searchFor);

        if ($this->searchType=='normal') {
            $this->computeNormalSearch();       
        }
        if ($this->searchType=='fulltext') {    
            $this->computeFullSearch($this->databaseType);
        }
        if ($this->searchType=='boolean fulltext') {
            $this->computeMySQLFullSearch($this->searchType);
        }
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   setSearchTerm
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Sets the expression to search for
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   searchFor - the expression
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function setSearchTerm($searchFor){
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $keywords = @$_GET[$searchFor];
        } else {
            $keywords = addslashes(@$_GET[$searchFor]);
        }
        $this->searchFor = stripslashes(strtolower($keywords));
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   computeNormalSearch
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Computes the SQL for the normal search
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   
    // RETURNS:
    //   
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function computeNormalSearch() {
        $searchFor = $this->searchFor;
        $like = $this->sql[$this->databaseType]['like'];
        if ($searchFor) {
            $searchCond = explode(" and ", $searchFor);
            for ($condIdx=0;$condIdx<count($searchCond);$condIdx++) {
                if ($searchCond[$condIdx]!='') {
                    if ($condIdx!=0) {
                        $this->whereCondition .= " AND (";
                    } else {
                        $this->whereCondition .= " (";
                    }   
                    $searchCond[$condIdx] = str_replace(" or "," ", $searchCond[$condIdx]);
                    $expr = "/\"([^\"]*)\"/m";
                    $matches = array();
                    preg_match_all($expr, $searchCond[$condIdx], $matches);
                    $searchCond[$condIdx] = preg_replace($expr, "", $searchCond[$condIdx]);
                    $searchWords = explode(" ", $searchCond[$condIdx]);
                    if (is_array($matches[1])) {            
                        foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {             
                            array_push($searchWords, $value);
                        }
                    }
                    $first = true;
                    for ($i=0;$i<count($searchWords);$i++) {
                        if ($searchWords[$i]!='') {
                            if (!$first) {
                                $this->whereCondition .= " OR (";
                            } else {
                                $this->whereCondition .= " (";
                            }
                            $first = false;
                            $this->whereCondition .= " col1_cah $like '%".addslashes($searchWords[$i])."%' ";
                            for ($relIdx=2; $relIdx <= 5; $relIdx++) {
                                $this->whereCondition .= " OR col".$relIdx."_cah $like '%".addslashes($searchWords[$i])."%' ";
                                if ($relIdx==5) $this->whereCondition .= ") ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $this->whereCondition .= " ) ";
                }
            }
            $this->orderBy      .= " importance_cah DESC";
        } else {
            $this->whereCondition .= " 1=-1 ";
            $this->orderBy      .= " importance_cah DESC";      
        }
    }
        
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   getScore
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Calculates the importance score 
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   text - text to search in
    //   text - text to search in
    //   searchFor - keywords
    // RETURNS:
    //   the importance score for the keywords
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    function getScore($text) 
    {
        $searchFor = $this->searchFor;
        $textLo = strtolower($text);
        $expr = "/\"([^\"]*)\"/m";
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all($expr, $searchFor, $matches);
        $searchFor = preg_replace($expr, "", $searchFor);
        $searchFor = str_replace('"','',$searchFor);
        $nrWords = count(explode(" ", $text));
        $searchWords = explode(" ", $searchFor);
        if (is_array($matches[1])) {
            foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
                array_push($searchWords, $value);
            }
        }
        $nrSearchWords = count($searchWords);
        $mainWordIdx = 0;
        $mainWord = "";
        
        if ($nrSearchWords==1) {
            $nrOccur = substr_count($textLo, strtolower($searchFor));
            $score = $nrOccur/$nrWords;
            return $score;
        } else {
            $score = 0;
            $allWords = true;
            for ($i=0;$i<$nrSearchWords;$i++) {
                if ($searchWords[$i]!='') {
                    $nrOccur = substr_count($textLo, strtolower($searchWords[$i]));     
                    if (!$nrOccur) {
                        $allWords = false;
                    }
                    $score += $nrOccur/$nrWords;        
                }
            }
            if ($allWords) {
                $score *= 5;
            }
            return $score;
        }
    }
    
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   getOrderedArray
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Makes a sort operation on the results for the normal search using the importance score
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   recSet - recordset object containing the results
    //   searchFor - keywords
    // RETURNS:
    //   array with the results in the right order
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function getOrderedArray($recSet, $start, $length)
    {
        $searchFor = $this->searchFor;
        $ordArr = array();
        $i = 0;
        $row_recSet = mysql_fetch_assoc($recSet);
        do {
            $fieldsArr = array();
            $fieldsArr['title_cah'] = $row_recSet['title_cah'];
            $fieldsArr['shortdesc_cah'] = $row_recSet['shortdesc_cah'];
            $fieldsArr['url_cah'] = $row_recSet['url_cah'];
            $score = 0;
            for ($j=1;$j<5;$j++) {
                $score += $this->importanceArray[$j] * $this->getScore($row_recSet['col'.$j.'_cah'], $searchFor);
            }
            $fieldsArr['score'] = $score * $row_recSet['importance_cah'];
            $ordArr[$i] = $fieldsArr;
            $i++;
        } while ($row_recSet = mysql_fetch_assoc($recSet));
        $ready = false;
        $nrRec = mysql_num_rows($recSet); 
        while(!$ready) {
            $ready = true;
            for($i=0;$i<$nrRec-1;$i++) {
                if ($ordArr[$i]['score']<$ordArr[$i+1]['score']) {
                    $aux = $ordArr[$i];
                    $ordArr[$i] = $ordArr[$i+1];
                    $ordArr[$i+1] = $aux;
                    $ready = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return array_slice($ordArr, $start, $length);
    }
    
    function computeFullSearch($dbType)
    {
        $searchFor = $this->searchFor;
        switch ($dbType) {
            case 'MySQL' : $this->computeMySQLFullSearch($this->searchType); break;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   computeMySQLFullSearch
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //      Computes the SQL for the fulltext search 
    //  
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   searchFor - search expression
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   nothing
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function computeMySQLFullSearch($fullType){
        $searchFor = $this->searchFor;
        if ($searchFor) {
            $searchCond = explode(" and ", $searchFor);
            $first = true;
            for ($condIdx=0;$condIdx<count($searchCond);$condIdx++) {
                if ($searchCond[$condIdx]!='') {
                    if ($condIdx!=0) {
                        $this->whereCondition .= " AND (";
                    } else {
                        $this->whereCondition .= " (";
                    }   
                    $searchCond[$condIdx] = str_replace(" or "," ", $searchCond[$condIdx]);
                    if (!$first) {
                        $this->orderBy .= " + ";
                    } else {
                        $this->orderBy .= " ( ";
                    }
                    $first = false;
                    $this->whereCondition .= sprintf($this->sql['MySQL']['fulltext_where'][$fullType], 1, addslashes($searchCond[$condIdx]));
                    $this->orderBy      .= " (".sprintf($this->sql['MySQL']['fulltext_order'][$fullType], 1, addslashes($searchCond[$condIdx]), $this->importanceArray[1]).") ";
                    for ($relIdx=2; $relIdx <= 5; $relIdx++) {
                        $this->orderBy      .= " + (".sprintf($this->sql['MySQL']['fulltext_order'][$fullType], $relIdx, addslashes($searchCond[$condIdx]), $this->importanceArray[$relIdx]).") ";
                        $this->whereCondition .= " OR ".sprintf($this->sql['MySQL']['fulltext_where'][$fullType], $relIdx, addslashes($searchCond[$condIdx]));
                    }
                    $this->whereCondition .= " ) ";
                }
            }
            $this->orderBy      .= ") * importance_cah ";
            $this->searchColumns = ", ".$this->orderBy." as score ";    
            $this->orderBy      .= " DESC";
        } else {
            $this->whereCondition = " 1=-1 ";
            $this->orderBy = " importance_cah DESC ";
        }
    }
    

    
    function getKeywords() {
        if ($this->searchFor) {
            return stripslashes(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $this->searchFor)); 
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   getSearchColumns
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Gets the aditional search columns
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   String with the column names or false if no aditional search columns
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function getSearchColumns() {
        if (isset($this->searchColumns))
            return $this->searchColumns;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   getWhereConditions
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Gets the where conditions for the SQL in the Advanced Recordset
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   String with the conditions or false if none defined
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function getWhereCondition(){
        if (isset($this->whereCondition))
            return $this->whereCondition;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   getOrderBy
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Gets the order by statement for the SQL in the Advanced Recordset
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   none
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   String with the order by statement or false if not defined
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function getOrderBy(){
        if (isset($this->orderBy))
            return $this->orderBy;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:
    //   formatDescription
    //
    // DESCRIPTION:
    //   Formats the description of each result for hilighting the found words
    //
    // ARGUMENTS:
    //   text - the description text
    //
    // RETURNS:
    //   the formatted text
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function cleanText($text)
    {
        $text = stripslashes(str_replace(array(" and "," or ","\""), " ", strtolower($text)));
        return $text;
    }
    
    function formatDescription($text){
        $maxChars = 100;
        $font = array(0=>"<span class=\"highlight\">",1=>"</span>");
        $searchFor = $this->searchFor;
        if(!trim($text)) //empty result
            return "";
        $ltext      = strtolower($text);
        if ($this->databaseType=='MySQL' && $this->searchType=='fulltext') {
            $searchFor = $this->cleanText($searchFor);
        }
        $expr = "/\"([^\"]*)\"/m";
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all($expr, $searchFor, $matches);
        $searchFor = preg_replace($expr,"",$searchFor);
        $searchFor = $this->cleanText($searchFor);      
        $arrSearchFor   = explode(" ",$searchFor);
        if (is_array($matches[1])) {
            foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
                array_push($arrSearchFor, $value);
            }
        }
        if (strlen($text) > 100) {
            foreach ($arrSearchFor as $key=>$value) {
                if ($value!='') {   
                    $pos = strpos($ltext, $value);
                    if ($pos) break;
                }
            }
            $leftLength = $pos;
            $rightLength = strlen(substr($ltext, $pos));
            if ($leftLength < 50) {
                $start = 0;
                $startStr = "";
                $endStr = "...";
            } else if ($rightLength < 50) {
                $start = $pos - (100 - $rightLength);
                $startStr = "...";
                $endStr = "";
            } else {
                $start = $pos - 50;
                $startStr = "...";
                $endStr = "...";
            }
            $firstSpace = 0;
            $lastSpace = strlen($text);
            if ($start!=0) {
                $firstSpace = strrpos(substr($text, 0, $start), " ");
            }
            if ($start + 100 <strlen($text)) {
                $lastSpace = strpos($text, " ", $start + 100);
            }
            $text = $startStr.substr($text, $firstSpace, $lastSpace - $firstSpace).$endStr;     
        } 
        
        $ltext = strtolower($text);
        $indexArr = array();    
        for ($i=0;$i<count($arrSearchFor);$i++) {
            if ($arrSearchFor[$i]!='') {
                $offset = 0;
                for ($j=0;$j<substr_count($ltext, $arrSearchFor[$i]);$j++) {
                        $offset = strpos($ltext, $arrSearchFor[$i], $offset);
                        $indexArr[] = array($offset, 0, $i);
                        $offset += strlen($arrSearchFor[$i]);
                        $indexArr[] = array($offset, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        $ready=false;
        while(!$ready) {
            $ready = true;
            for($i=0;$i<count($indexArr)-1;$i++) {
                if ($indexArr[$i][0]>$indexArr[$i+1][0]) {
                    $aux = $indexArr[$i];
                    $indexArr[$i] = $indexArr[$i+1];
                    $indexArr[$i+1] = $aux;
                    $ready = false;
                }
            }
        } 
        $displayText = "";
        $end = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i<count($indexArr); $i++) {
            if ($i!=0) {
                $start = $indexArr[$i-1][0];
            } else {
                $start = 0;
            }
            $end = $indexArr[$i][0];
            $type = $indexArr[$i][1];
            $displayText .= substr($text, $start, $end-$start).$font[$type];
        }
        $displayText .= substr($text, $end);
        return $displayText;
    }
}
//end class
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like the code made it up correctly. Visit this GitHub for clearer view of code: https://github.com/lchabolla/KT_MXSearch.class.php

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your source is nearly 900 lines long - which wouldn't be suitable for SO anyway. The relevant parts (the issued `CREATE TABLE` statements) are enough to answer your question.

Comment: On another note: [InnoDB does support FULLTEXT search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) - make sure you're not having other issues in your codebase.

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the input ccKep. InnoDB added support for FULLTEXT on 5.6 from my research. But yes, I think the issue is in the CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: You are using `mysql_*` interface??  Abandon ye all hope!

Comment: @RickJames what would you recommend?

Comment: `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally not a PHP problem, your `CREATE TABLE` statements don't specify a storage engine (which they probably should if they rely on MyISAM features).

A quick look at [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engine-setting.html) leaves you with 2 possible solutions:

1. Add the required storage engine to the CREATE TABLE statement
2. Change the default storage engine

> If you omit the ENGINE option, the default storage engine is used. The default engine is InnoDB as of MySQL 5.5.5 (MyISAM before 5.5.5). You can specify the default engine by using the --default-storage-engine server startup option, or by setting the default-storage-engine option in the my.cnf configuration file.

Comment: ccKep, I've added the following line to the CREATE statement ENGINE=MyISAM since I can't change the default engine. Will be monitoring the functionality and will report back if this has fixed the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: After adding the ENGINE option to the CREATE statement the table now stays in MyISAM. Thanks for your help ccKep

Comment: Upgrade MySQL so you can get `FULLTEXT` in InnoDB.

Comment: @RickJames not my server, so I had to find a workaround. I learned some new stuff though!